# "Extending" Dockerfile to modify a file, caused sonarqube to fail

Tags: docker, sonarqube

I am attempting to use Sonarqube with CloudRun, and for that I need to support the use of an environment variable PORT when starting the docker image. So I tried to "extend" my `Dockerfile` like:

```
FROM sonarqube:7.9-community
WORKDIR $SONARQUBE_HOME
COPY sonar.properties $SONARQUBE_HOME
COPY run.sh ./bin/
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["./bin/run.sh"]
```

I modified sonar.properties to include a line like:

```
sonar.web.port=__PORT__
```

Then I modify `run.sh` with the line:

```
sed "s/__PORT__/$PORT/g" ./sonar.properties > conf/sonar.properties
```

And tried starting the server like:

```
docker run -e PORT=8080 sonarqube-custom
```

The logs shows nothing wrong ...

```
2019.11.15 02:55:04 INFO  web[][o.s.s.q.ProjectsInWarningDaemon] Counting number of projects in warning is enabled.
2019.11.15 02:55:04 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.p.PlatformLevelStartup] Running Community Edition
2019.11.15 02:55:04 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] WebServer is operational
2019.11.15 02:55:04 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[web] is up
2019.11.15 02:55:04 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='ce', ipcIndex=3, logFilenamePrefix=ce]] from [/opt/sonarqube]: /usr/local/openjdk-11/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube/temp --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.*|[::1] -cp ./lib/common/*:/opt/sonarqube/lib/jdbc/h2/h2-1.3.176.jar org.sonar.ce.app.CeServer /opt/sonarqube/temp/sq-process3988720795271274831properties
2019.11.15 02:55:04 INFO  web[][o.s.s.q.ProjectsInWarningDaemon] Counting number of projects in warning will be disabled as there are no more projects in warning.
2019.11.15 02:55:05 INFO  ce[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting ce
2019.11.15 02:55:05 INFO  ce[][o.s.ce.app.CeServer] Compute Engine starting up...
2019.11.15 02:55:06 INFO  ce[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2019.11.15 02:55:06 INFO  ce[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.join.ParentJoinPlugin]
2019.11.15 02:55:06 INFO  ce[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.percolator.PercolatorPlugin]
2019.11.15 02:55:06 INFO  ce[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2019.11.15 02:55:07 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.e.EsClientProvider] Connected to local Elasticsearch: [127.0.0.1:9001]
2019.11.15 02:55:07 INFO  ce[][o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:h2:tcp://127.0.0.1:9092/sonar
2019.11.15 02:55:07 WARN  ce[][o.s.db.dialect.H2] H2 database should be used for evaluation purpose only.
2019.11.15 02:55:08 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.p.ServerFileSystemImpl] SonarQube home: /opt/sonarqube
2019.11.15 02:55:08 INFO  ce[][o.s.c.c.CePluginRepository] Load plugins
2019.11.15 02:55:10 INFO  ce[][o.s.c.c.ComputeEngineContainerImpl] Running Community edition
2019.11.15 02:55:10 INFO  ce[][o.s.ce.app.CeServer] Compute Engine is operational
2019.11.15 02:55:10 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[ce] is up
2019.11.15 02:55:10 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is up
```

But when I try to access the URL `localhost:8080` it fails

[image]

Comment: are you using MACos for sonarqube container ?

Comment: If you start your container as `docker run -e PORT=8080 sonarqube-custom` you're not going to be able to contact anything on `localhost:8080` because you haven't published any ports (using e.g. the `-p` option to `docker run`).

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan yes I am on a mac now

Comment: Sonarqube is using default port : 9000, can you share `run.sh` file ?

Comment: try `docker run -p "8080:8080" -e PORT=8080` sonarqube-custom, it will publish host 8080 to container 8080. I think, You dont need to change and add `sonar.web.port=__PORT__`, let sonarqube listen on any port and publish the specific host port to container.

Comment: @larsks thank you, you can actually post as answer and I mark it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start your container as docker run -e PORT=8080 sonarqube-custom you're not going to be able to contact anything on localhost:8080 because you haven't published any ports (using e.g. the -p option to docker run).

It's important to note that you probably don't need to modify the sonarqube configuration at all: you could just `docker run -p 8080:9000 ...` to expose the service on port 8080 on your host, despite it running on port 9000 inside the container.

Comment: last useful thing- the `EXPOSE` command doesn't do what you think it does. It marks that port so that if you pass `-P` to `docker run` it will pick a random port to map to that port. In the last six years, I still haven't found an actual use for the `-P` command or EXPOSE honestly.

Comment: I think I need the PORT patch because CloudRun requires the port to be set using env var

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the difference between `expose` flag(`-e`) and `publish` flag(`-p`). Imagine your container like a computer and your docker stack (The collection of services) like a network. You have a computer firewall and a network firewall in place.

The computer firewall opens the port to allow ingress traffic when you `expose` your port. So, as long as the port is not exposed, the service listening on the port is only accessible from inside the container (or computer in our reference). This configuration is helpful for cases where you want your service to be accessible from inside the network only. For example, a database that interacts with the business-logic layer but, should not be exposed to the open internet. When it is exposed, the traffic from other containers of the same stack (or other computers on the same network) can access the service but, it cannot be accessed from other networks as the network firewall doesn't allow any ingress traffic.

This is where port `publish` comes in. When you `expose` **and** `publish` your port, the service listening on the network can now be accessed not only from containers other services in the stack (other computers in the network) but also from outside the network. This configuration is good for services with which the users interact. For example, the user-interface layer of your applications.